# how to use power method matlab to get the highest eigenvalue

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvector

I am trying to use the

> [power method](http://www.prenhall.com/bretscher1e/html/proj10.html)

get the highest eigenvalue and its corrresponding eigenvector from a randamly matrix generated by Matlab (it should be square and the size is specified by user, can anyone help and advise me how to modify/add statements to that code to get what I need? please help!

```
    function [ v d] = power_method( A )
% for finding the largest eigen value by power method
input ( ' Enter the size n*n matrix A : \n')
A=single(1*rand(size,size));
% loop starts

while 
    X( : ,k+ 1 ) = A*X( : ,k); %POWER METHOD formula
    % normalizing the obtained vector 
    [ v i ] = max(abs(A*X( : ,k+ 1 )));
    E = X( : ,k+ 1 );
    e = E( i,1);
    X(:,k+1) = X(:,k+1)/e;
    k = k + 1;  
end


fprintf (' The largest eigen value after %d itarations is  %7.7f  \n', k, e)
disp('and the corresponding eigen vector is ')
X( : ,k)
```

Comment: You should avoid or at least indicate cross-postings like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288319/power-method-matlab to avoid duplicate efforts at answers or links.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

here my source in Delphi(pascal), you can use the algorithm

```
Lambda:=0;
  Count:=0;
  Err:=1;
  for i:=1 to MaxIterasi do
  begin

   for k:=1 to n do
   begin
    Y[k]:=0;
    for j:=1 to n do
    begin
     Y[k]:=Y[k]+A[k,j]*X[j];
    end;
   end;


   MaxElement:=0;
   for j:=1 to n do
   begin
    if(abs(Y[j])>abs(MaxElement)) then
     MaxElement:=Y[j];
   end;

   C1:=MaxElement;

    for k:=1 to n do
     Y[k]:=(1/C1)*Y[k];


   for k:=1 to n do
    X[k]:=Y[k];

    Lambda:=C1;
  end;

 GridEigen.Cells[0,n+3]:='Lambda=';
 GridEigen.Cells[1,n+3]:=floattostr(lambda);
 for k:=1 to n do
 begin
  GridEigen.Cells[k,n+4]:='X'+inttostr(k)+'='+floattostr(X[k]);
 end;

 GridEigen.Cells[n+2,0]:='Result:';
 GridEigen.Cells[n+2,1]:='Lambda='+floattostr(lambda);
 for k:=1 to n do
 begin
  GridEigen.Cells[n+2,k+2]:='X'+inttostr(k)+'='+floattostr(X[k]);
 end;

[enter image description here][1]
```